# Git commit "error: Could not connect to socket. Is the agent running? fatal: failed to write commit object" after reverting from 1password ssh-agent

Tags: git, macos, ssh, 1password

Couldn't find the answer to this anywhere but finally figured out the problem and wanted to share the solution.

Problem: After using 1Password ssh agent, trying to `git commit` through a terminal on a Mac yields the following error:

```
error: Could not connect to socket. Is the agent running?

fatal: failed to write commit object
```

Solution:
1Password modifies two files where it specifies which ssh to use; `~/.gitconfig` and `~/.ssh/config`. After removing 1Password as the default ssh agent, these two files have to be reverted as well:

In `~/.ssh/config`, remove this:

```
Host *
  IdentityAgent "~/Library/Group Containers/2BUA8C4S2C.com.1password/t/agent.sock"
```

And in your `~/.gitconfig`, replace this:

```
[gpg "ssh"]
    program = /Applications/1Password.app/Contents/MacOS/op-ssh-sign
```

with this path to wherever your preferred `ssh` is (probably `/usr/bin/ssh`):

```
[gpg "ssh"]
    program = /usr/bin/ssh
```

This solution applies to both command-line git and GitHub Desktop clients.

Comment: This was helpful to me! As a gentle suggestion you may want to move the solution into an answer to your own question :)

Comment: (re-)starting 1Password as Jesper said below might have worked as well, instead of disableing 1Password as SSH agent.

Answer (score 39):

I noticed that my 1Password wasn't running. So I started my 1Password application and it worked right away.

Comment: Another 1Password-related bug I just resolved, I found this line in my `.gitconfig` was missing the `"`s around the `program` string. I replaced the quotes and retried `git commit` this re-prompted me for access and everything worked again!

```program = "/Applications/1Password.app/Contents/MacOS/op-ssh-sign"```

Answer (score 7):

This error probably means that you've set up 1Password to sign your commits, most likely involving a fingerprint reader. **But you have been signed out of 1Password.**

Log back in to 1Password and it should work again!

Comment: This answer saved A LOT of time, 1Password was not on my shortlist of troubleshooting ideas

Answer (score -1):

The following is applicable to a Linux operating system. It is similar for MacOs

1. Remove the following lines

```
Host *
    IdentityAgent ~/.1password/agent.sock
```

from the `~/.ssh/config` file

2. Remove the following lines

```
[gpg "ssh"]
  program = "/opt/1Password/op-ssh-sign"
```

from the `~/.gitconfig` file

Comment: I know the questioner answered their own question, but they didn't make an answer. this is an answer.

Comment: In my case I had to remove other lines as well: `[gpg] format = ssh` and `[commit] gpgsign = true`.

Comment: Do you mean `~/.gitconfig`? Those lines don't appear in `~/.ssh/config`